# Entering an image in mysql 8.0 results in a null value or only with 4 bytes

Tags: java

When I insert an image into my table in the mysql database in java, nothing unusual happens, like error or some exception, sign that everything went well. but when i go to mysql i see the field empty or containing 4 bytes only.am working with java 9 and mysql 8.0.15

If anyone has ever faced this kind of problem or knows how to help me, thank you in advance.

this is the code

```
try(PreparedStatement ps = Conexão.conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO 
usuario(avatar, `desc`) VALUES(?,?)")) {

  ps.setBinaryStream(1,ipstram,longitudeBites);
  ps.setString(2,"Desc"+ Time.from(Instant.now()));

  if (new Usuario().inserir(ps)) {
      jfxSnackbar.show("Usuario Inserido com exito","OK",5000,event1 -> 
      jfxSnackbar.close());
      ipstram=null;
            }
  else {
      jfxSnackbar.show("Inserção Mal Sucesida","OK",5000,event1 -> 
      jfxSnackbar.close());
      }

    } catch (SQLException e) {               
      e.printStackTrace();
      }



public class Usuario{

 public boolean inserir(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
        if (ps.executeUpdate() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the schema of your database ?

Comment: Is this running in an application server? You swallow the SQLException, you may need to check the server logs. In either case, a [mcve] would help. Nobody can reproduce the problem with the code you posted.

Comment: My database schema only has a table that has the following structure: <pre><ode>CREATE TABLE usuario (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  avatar MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL,
  desc VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)); </pre></pre>

Comment: No, I'm running it from the IDE. Well, the weird thing is that it doesn't show any messages indicating any errors. @Robert

Answer (score 0):

From the question we cannot see what `ipstram` and `longitudeBites` contain.

In fact best would be, if you verified their validity yourself. Check this:

```
byte[] data = ipstram.readAllBytes();
logger.info("### Data length: {}, expected: {}", data.length, longitudeBites);
Files.write(Paths.get("/.../temp.jpg"), data);
ipstram = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);

ps.setBinaryStream(1, ipstram, longitudeBites);
ps.setString(2,"Desc"+ Time.from(Instant.now()));
```

Comment: I managed to overcome the problem thanks to your help. Thank you so much friend, you helped me a lot.

The problem was that the <pre><code>ipstram</code></pre>  variable was emptied before I sent data to the database.